# How to setting logstash to listen snmptrap?

Tags: logstash

I am a new to lostash and elastichsearch. I want to collection logs of network devices by snmptrap. I have a problem with logstash.

```
+logstash-snmptrap.conf

input {
      snmptrap {
           community => "public"
           port => 160
           type => "snmp_trap"
             }
         }

output {
if [type] == "snmp_trap" {
   file {
     codec => "rubydebug"
     flush_interval => 1
     path => "/tmp/logstash-snmptrap.log"
         }
      }
}
```

I didn't get any error msg when i execute the command as follows,

```
root@pc:~# /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash-   
snmptrap.conf

Settings: Default filter workers: 1
Logstash startup completed
Settings: Default filter workers: 1
Logstash startup completed
```

but I can't find the file "/tmp/logstash-snmptrap.log" , 
what's wrong with my logstash config ?

Answer (score 0):

I normally see snmptrap run on port 162.  Are you sure that yours is on 160?

Also, don't run the process as root.  Use a port forwarder (e.g. iptables), to send 162 to 1062 (the default port that snmptrap listens on).

Remember that you will lose traps if logstash is down.  Previously, I had a small logstash installation that would listen to snmptrap and syslog and write them to redis, to be read by the main logstash when it was up.  I replaced this with snmptrapd writing to a local file and letting logstash read from that file.  I had more control over the input than logstash gave me.

Comment: now , i have modify the port from 160 to 1062 in  logstash-snmptrap.conf                                          and check the netstat as follow :                                                                                                                                                    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:162             0.0.0.0:*  udp6       0      0 :::1062                 :::*        10771/java   ,but still can't find the file "/tmp/logstash-snmptrap.log" ??

Comment: And something is forwarding 162 to 1062?

Comment: it's looks like the trap didn't forward to 1062 , do you know how to forward the trap from 162 to 1062 ?

Comment: In my answer, I said, "Use a port forwarder (e.g. iptables), to send 162 to 1062 (the default port that snmptrap listens on)."